# Baruch Hu Ubaruch Shmo-Meaning

Tags: tefilla, theology

I am looking for a good explanation of the phrase, "Baruch Hu Ubaruch Shmo".i.e. why do we praise both Hashem and his "name" separately? Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to miyodeya.com. Thanks for your interesting question. Please stay around and check out the many questions and answers on this sight.

Comment: The same would apply to e.g. Baruch shem kevod malchuto. Good question!

Comment: Thanks for asking this interesting question! I've asked it myself in the past!

Answer (score 7):

The Siach Yitzchok, found in the Siddur Ishei Yisroel of the Gra"h, explains the phrase in the third blessing of Shemoneh Esrei אתה קדוש ושמך קדוש - You are sanctified and Your name is sanctified - that You refers to Hashem's essence, and Your name refers to His actions which are linked to His name.

Baruch Hu would mean blessing Hashem "Himself" whereas Baruch Shmo would mean blessing His actions in this world, the way in which we perceive Him.

Answer (score -1):

HaShems design of creation was accomplished with various structures, one of which is the names that are used to reference HaShem in different purposes\functions. He (of baruch hu) is beyond all these manifestations and His name (Ubaruch Shmo) is a most ephemeral reference to a topmost manifestation. So my understanding of Baruch Hu Ubaruch Shmo is blessesd is He of beyond all creation and blessed is His name the cause of all creation.